# Getting Vilkas Sword back from Eorlund Gray-Mane

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did the quest Take up Arms where you get the Vilkas Sword. Now, I didn't use magic on him to defeat him. However, once I got the sword to Eorlund Gray-Mane, he asked me to go and give a shield to Aela, which I did. As soon as I left, he started sharpening the blade. Since then, I can't seem to find a way to get it back.

Do you ever get it back? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a bug, it's just the end of that particular quest. You don't need to bring the sword back to Vilkas.

Comment: Humm, so you just lose it... I thought the guy gave the sword to me so I could use it lol!

Comment: Aaaaaand, special thanks for not spoiling anything :)